How can I force IntelliJ to resolve conflicts, which are already committed in a file by another person
Using GIT, I checked out a branch from the remote repository, which another person had worked on. One of the files has conflicts, which are already committed, so the file contains marks like <<<<<<< HEAD etc.
Now, is there any way to run IntelliJ conflicts resolving tool, to resolve these conflicts? Or do I need to resolve them by hand?

As far as git is concerned, those are no longer conflicts. They are now just the content of the files. I don't think the common tools have a way to retroactively treat them as conflicts.

when conflict happens, you can use the built-in merge tool, do this steps -

open project where the conflicts need to be resolved.

checkout the branch with conflicts:
git checkout your-branch


Open the Version Control Tool in  View > Tool Windows > Version Control.

In the Version Control tool window, go to the Local Changes tab. You will see a list of files with conflicts, marked with a red triangle.

Initiate the Merge Tool:

Right-click on the conflicted file.
Select Git > Resolve Conflicts.


Merge Tool will open a three-way merge tool where you can see:

Changes from the current branch on left side.

Changes from the branch you are merging on right side.

and in center, resulting file where you can choose which changes to keep.

Use the buttons above the panes to accept changes from either side or both. You can also manually edit the center pane to resolve the conflict.



Once you have resolved all conflicts in the file, click Apply to save the merged result and mark the conflict as resolved.

After resolving all conflicts, commit the changes:
git add path/to/conflicted-file
git commit -m "Resolved merge conflicts in path/to/conflicted-file"



do this steps , so you dont have to  manually edit the conflicted code.
but yes , once the conflict markers are committed, Git no longer considers them as conflicts and now that is part of the file content.
you can still do like this -

Open the file containing the conflict markers.

Look for the conflict markers:

<<<<<<< HEAD - this is for start of your changes.

======= - this Separates your changes from the incoming changes.

>>>>>>> branch-name - shows the end of the incoming changes.

now simply Decide which changes you want to keep: the changes between <<<<<<< HEAD and ======= (your changes) or the changes between ======= and >>>>>>> branch-name (the incoming changes).

Edit the file to keep the needed changes and remove the conflict markers.



After resolving the conflicts, Test It.

then stage the resolved file:
git add path/to/file


Commit the resolved changes:
git commit -m " resolved conflicts in path/to/file"





